# how can i copy multiple dependencies to multiple folders using maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

we are going with a ant-Maven configuration,

**how i build the application**   : through ant's build.xml called from maven's ant-run plugin

**what is needed to run build.xml**: to have dependencies in a lib folder

**issue faced**   :  we have two folders for dependencies, which need to hold different dependencies, but dependency plugin will copy dependencies to only one folder.

how can i generate different dependencies to more than one folder ( lib and lib-external) .

Comment: the purpose of using the maven is just to include dependencies.

Comment: Migrate the projects to Maven. That's it..

Comment: @khmarbaise... thanks but there are a lot to migrate, hence we are going with this approach, otherwise it would have been easier i guess.

Comment: update: we migrated to Maven.